# Chrome padding bug

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, padding, twitter-bootstrap

## Context

I have this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Un employé, un standard ou un numéro..." />
```

With CSS property: `padding: 4px`.

The rendering:

[image]

For info, I use Bootstrap for the CSS.

## Investigation

On the screen, Chrome just do `padding-left: 4px` instead of `padding: 4px`.

I tried `padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px` and `padding-top: 4px; padding-right: 4px; etc`.

Same issue.

Strange thing, I tried `padding-top: 4px` alone and it works. Same thing with any `padding-xxx`.

Finally I tried `padding: 4px` on a `input` out my page and it works.

## Question

What is the problem?

Comment: Do you have any `height` value set through CSS for your `input`? Try removing it if so, and see if it helps.

Comment: It works thanks. Post a answer for I accept it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have any `height` value set through CSS for your `input`? Try removing it if so, and see if it helps.

*(comment copied for the answer acceptance.)*

Answer (score 2):

Chrome applies default styles to most form elements. We counter this by adding `-webkit-appearance: none;` to the style of the `<input>`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have set padding or height on the element, please try to increase/decrease or if it will not work then remove it and test again it might help. Please try to test it simultaneously in all browsers so you can make it similar in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem again with Bootstrap and it was because I had `<!DOCYTPE>` instead of `<!DOCTYPE html>`.